# Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update In Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

```
).outputMode(
    "update"
).start()
```

updated_df = func(spark, df_with_signals)

query=updated_df.writeStream.queryName("display2").format(
"delta"
).foreachBatch(
lambda dataframe, _: fun2(spark, dataframe)
).trigger(
processingTime="2 seconds"
).outputMode(
"update"
)

here we have two streaming queries  first streaming query we do the merge operation like insert and delete
and after that we are doing couple of transofmrations and the second streaming query starts here we are updating the records
but when we send the mutiple events at the same time we have encountering the below issue
"Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update," is there any possibilty for retry mechanism or any other approach